# IBM Worklight - Is iPod Touch supported?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I can't find a definitive place that list all the various devices and their versions that IBM Worklight supports. I do not see iPod Touch in the targets in Xcode, but I assume that if iPhone (iOS 5 or 6) is supported and works, then so too should iPod Touch. Does anyone know if it works?

Comment: Well the iPod Touch **runs** iOS, so it's obviously supported.  You just lose all the features that the iPhone has and the iPod Touch doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPod, iPhone, iPad running iOS 5, 6 or 7 are supported.

For a full list, visit:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=1343665214557

Note that it is the OS that matters, not the specific iDevice.

Creating a Worklight project and application with the iPhone environment essentially means it will also work on an iPod Touch; the only difference is whichever feature exists in one device and not the other, for example - 3G and WiFi in an iPhone versus WiFi or none in an iPod Touch, or making phone calls in an iPhone whereas this is not possible in an iPod Touch, etc...

In the case of Worklight, the lack of 3G or WiFi means that you won't be able to use the Geolocation feature in an iPod Touch, for example. You can follow this logic for any other feature...